# for loop IndentationError: unexpected indent

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

When I run my code, I get an error in the `for` loop line.

This is the error:

> File.readlines(): IndentationError: unexpected indent

And this is my code:

```
File = open('/home/shar/Desktop/list','r')
      for line in File.readlines():
```

Are there any ideas?

Comment: Well, you indented the `for` line.  Why did you do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to indent the `for` since you get the file object by assignment.

```
File = open('/home/shar/Desktop/list','r')
for line in File.readlines():
```

Answer (score 0):

When using a [`for` loop](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements), it should look something like this:

```
for x in y:
    ...
```

You don't need to indent the initial line; only the lines contained inside the loop itself.